# How to create an "empty" space in an executable at a definite address (gcc,linux)?

Tags: linux, gcc, executable, portable-executable

What I essentially want to do is have another program write data into this "empty space" for the executable to "work" on

I thought of appending a signature to the application and then writing the data, searching for it later, but that doesn't quite sound right...

Now, other important thing ... I know it should be possible to create a code cave by using code like :

```
void function(void) {
__asm {
nop
nop
nop
nop
};
}
```

then, even this is practically the same (apart from the fact that it will be in the .data section, so not executable):

```
const char data[3];
```

The problem then is that the other application will not have a definite address to write to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At least for PEs and ELFs, you can append data to the end of the executable without affecting the program at all.

A standard approach is to append your data to the executable, and then append a number indicating how many bytes have been appended.  The executable then opens itself for reading, looks at the last N bytes indicating the data length, and then `seek`s backwards by that value, to the beginning of the appended data.

[This article](http://users.iafrica.com/d/da/dart/zen/Articles/SelfExtract/Self%20Extract.html) goes into pretty good detail on how to use the above method to make a self-extracting executable.  That's a little different from what you want, but the principle of reading data contained in the executable remains the same.

Comment: That's how it's done in *most* non-compiler programs that generate unique executables based on the data you input -- most self-extracting compression programs, `py2exe` too, I think.

Answer (score 3):

Use an ld linker script to make a new section, and to reserve actual space in the file image. You also need to associate a symbol with the new data section. Perhaps it would be even easier to create a short assembly file instead, like this:

```
.section .myresource
.align 4
.globl myres
myres:
.fill 1048576
```

Then in your C code you would use the symbol to get the data, like this:

```
extern const int* myres;
```

Check out the binutils documentation here:
http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.19/

Comment: How do you suggest that the other application would get the offset then?

Comment: It could read the custom section by using the structures from <elf.h>

Answer (score 0):

you can do what you asked by using [linker scripts](http://www.nacad.ufrj.br/sgi/860-0247-001/sgi_html/ldLinker_scripts.html).

basically, function_name = address in the script.